# Invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void (*)(..)'

Tags: c++, void

I have error

> invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void (*)(void*, u_int8_t*, u_int8_t*, u_int16_t, void*) {aka void (*)(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, short unsigned int, void*)}' [-fpermissive]

```
void m_callback_friendrequest(Messenger *m, void (*function)(Messenger *m, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *), void *userdata)
{
    void (*handle_friendrequest)(void *, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *) = (void *)(function);//->error
    callback_friendrequest(&(m->fr), handle_friendrequest, m, userdata);
}
```

Comment: And? What's your question? In your code you explicitly cast `function` to `void *` type and then attempt to use the resultant `void *` value as an initializer for a function pointer. This will not work. This is what the compiler is telling you. Why are you casing `function` to `void *`???

Comment: @AndreyT people should stop posting light blue comments. It is awful and difficult to read :(

Answer (score 2):

In C I think your code would work, but C++ will not let you implicitly cast a `void*` into some other pointer type.  I would do

```
typedef void (*FunFriend)(void *, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *);

.
.
.
FunFriend handle_friendrequest = (FunFriend)function;
```

Comment: In C, the code would be equally invalid. -1 because you shouldn't be casting at all. Either the function is already of the correct type, and the cast does nothing, or the function is not of the correct type (as it is here), and a cast simply suppresses a correct and useful error message.

Comment: If the system uses the same representation for `void *` as `Messenger *` (almost all systems do), then the code is very likely to work.  Of course it is usually inadvisable to rely on undefined behaviour, but depending on OP's situation, it may be the most economic option.

Comment: C allows implict casts from void, thats why you can do `foo *bar = malloc(sizeof(foo))` in C and not C++.   As for the cast: yes he should probably define a wrapper function that takes a `void*` as its first argument and pass that.  Even then, he will Need a cast from `void*` to `Message*`.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala C does not allow implicit conversions from `void *` to function pointer types. It does not even require support for those conversions if written explicitly. C only allows implicit conversions from `void *` to object pointer types. But the cast that you suggest in your comment for a wrapper function, yes, from `void *` to `Message *` would be one that C implicitly allows.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer `handle_friendrequest` has type

```
void (*)(void *, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *)
```

Pointer `function` has type

```
void (*)(Messenger *, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *)
```

These are two different function pointer types, which are completely incompatible with each other. You cannot use `function` to initialize `handle_friendrequest`, period.

It looks like you tried to cast `function` to `void *` as a workaround, but this makes no sense whatsoever. It simply will not compile. It strange to see you ask this question (if I understood it correctly), since the compiler is complaining about a meaningless invalid cast you yourself inserted into the code.

You have to make sure both function pointers have identical types, including identical parameter lists. That will fix the problem and eliminate the need for any casts. As long as the parameter lists are different, there is no solution, aside from ugly hacks.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as the error message says. In the expression in your code, you have `(void *)(function)`.

That is of type `void *`. However you then assign that to a variable with function-pointer type. In general, it is not possible to convert between function pointers and object pointers, although some implementations may allow it.

If `Messenger` is actually a typedef for `void *` then  you can just remove the `(void *)` because `function` and `handle_friendrequest` would have the same type, so no cast is necessary.

If `Messenger` is not `void *` then your intended code will have undefined behaviour, because the function pointers have different types. Consider re-doing your design so that the function you are calling actually has the same prototype as the type of the function pointer.

If you really want to bull on with the undefined behaviour, the code would be:

```
{
    typedef void HANDLER(void *, uint8_t *, uint8_t *, u_int16_t, void *);
    HANDLER *handle_friendrequest = (HANDLER *)function;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void (*handle_friendrequest)(void *, u_int8_t *, u_int8_t *, u_int16_t, void *) =
        (void (*)(void*, u_int8_t*, u_int8_t*, u_int16_t, void*))function;
```

Of course function must be aware that it may take `void*`, not `Messenger *`